# Getting a hyperlink field/column to display data as a hyperlink from a SharePoint List, using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, sharepoint, hyperlink

I have what I think should be a simple issue to resolve, but it has taken me way too long to figure out.

The background on this is thus:  basically what I have is a SharePoint List that contains task items.  We have created a .js file and published it to the Site Assets section along with some jQuery files.  These files serve to pull data from that task list and use it in a new task list (for testing) using a CAML query.

Basically, what all this does is: using a webpart, allow us in a test segment of the SP site to take that test task list and re-sort it using drag and drop (we select any row and drag it to where we want it to be in the list and it drops right there).

So with all that, my actual problem is very simple.  On this drag and drop list, one of the columns is an Edit column.  It pulls a hyperlink field from the source task list.  In my test list, I cannot for the life of me get that link to display as a hyperlink, it will only display as text!
I am pretty new to integrating all this JavaScript, SharePoint, jQuery, etc so am probably missing something obvious.  I would be very grateful for any assistance and thank you in advance.
Here is the code I am using, followed by a little more explanation.  Everything works, except the link!

**Here is the CAML query, looking at the data from the list:**

```
function loadPrioritizedList() {
    $("#tasksUL").empty();
// TDs below have to be 3 more width than the headers 
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",    
        webURL: myURL,
        listName: targetListName,
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Priority_x0020_Number' /><FieldRef Name='Edit_x0020_Link' /><FieldRef Name='Priority' /><FieldRef Name='Top_x0020_Item_x003f_' /><FieldRef Name='Purpose' /><FieldRef Name='Work_x002d_Task_x0020_Order' /><FieldRef Name='Work_x0020_Status' /><FieldRef Name='DueDate' /><FieldRef Name='Task_x0020_Type' /></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: '<Query>' +
        '<OrderBy>' +
        '<FieldRef Name="Priority_x0020_Number" />' +
        '</OrderBy>' +
        '</Query>', 
        CAMLRowLimit: listrowlimit,
```

**And here is where I am using the data:**

```
     CAMLRowLimit: listrowlimit,  
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                    var tdHtml = "<tr class='sortable_row' id=" + $(this).attr("ows_ID") + ">";
                    tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:40px;\">" + PriorityFormat($(this).attr("ows_Priority_x0020_Number"));  + "</td>";
tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:40px;\">" + ($(this).attr("ows_Edit_x0020_Link")).split(", ")[1] + "</td>"; 
 tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:46px;\">" + $(this).attr("ows_Priority") + "</td>";
tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:40px;\">" + TopItem($(this).attr("ows_Top_x0020_Item_x003f_")) + "</td>";
tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:300px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_Purpose")) + "</td>";
 tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:125px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_Work_x002d_Task_x0020_Order")) + "</td>";    
tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:150px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_Work_x0020_Status")) + "</td>";
tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:100px;\">" + FormatDate($(this).attr("ows_DueDate")) + "</td>";
tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:75px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_Task_x0020_Type")) + "</td>";
 tdHtml = tdHtml + "</tr>";
                    $("#tasksUL").append(tdHtml);
```

**The data element that needs to be a hyperlink is:**   `<FieldRef Name='Edit_x0020_Link' />`

I was thinking I would have to format as a link here:

```
tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:40px;\">" + ($(this).attr("ows_Edit_x0020_Link")).split(", ")[1] + "</td>";
```

The data from the source table is a URL, followed by “, Edit” which in the source displays “Edit” as the link – if a user clicks that link, it opens the row (task) item to be able to edit it.  I am trying to replicate that here (hence the “.split”), but again, am only getting text back.  Same thing happens if I split for the URL instead of “Edit”.

**Here is the full code from the whole .js file:**

```
<link href="../SiteAssets/jquery-ui.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style type="text/css">
    #tasksUL {
        PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px
    }
    #tasksUL LI {
        PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.4em; MARGIN: 0px 3px 3px; PADDING-LEFT: 1.5em; PADDING-RIGHT: 0.4em; HEIGHT: 10px; FONT-SIZE: 1.4em; CURSOR: pointer; PADDING-TOP: 0.4em
    }
    #tasksUL LI SPAN {
        POSITION: absolute; MARGIN-LEFT: -1.3em
    }
    .listtable {
        font-size:10px;
        color:#333333;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #729ea5;
        border-collapse: collapse !important;
        position: relative;
overflow-y:auto;
float:left !important; 
    }
    .listtable_hdr th {
        font-size:10px;
        background-color:#acc8cc;
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 4px;
        border-style: solid;border-color: #729ea5;
        text-align:left;
    }
    .listtable tr {
        background-color:#d4e3e5;
    }
    .listtable td {
        font-size:10px;
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 4px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #729ea5;
        vertical-align:center;
border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .listtable_hdr
    {   /* this div used as a fixed column header above the porfolio table, so we set bkgrnd color here */
        position: static;    float: left;                        
    }
</style>
<script language="javascript" src="../SiteAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../SiteAssets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    //CONFIGURATION VARIABLES
    //Assumes that this list is on the same site as the WebPart
    var targetListName = "AI Test List";
    var myURL = "https://myteam.navair.navy.mil/air/68cbo/Sandbox"
    var updatecount = 100;
    var listrowlimit = 50;
    var tablewidth = 975;

    var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {

        var $originals = tr.children();
        var $helper = tr;

        $helper.children().each(function(index) {
            $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
        });
    $helper.width(tablewidth);

        $helper.css('background-color', '#d3e324');

        return $helper;
    };

    function PriorityFormat(item) {
        if (typeof item === 'undefined')
            return 0;
        else
            return parseInt(item);
    }

    function TopItem(item) {
        if (item == "1")
            return "Yes";
        else 
            return "No";
    }

    function StringChk(item) {
        if (typeof item === 'undefined')
            return "&nbsp;";
        else
            return item;
    }

    function FormatDate(item) {
        if (typeof item === 'undefined')
            return "&nbsp;";
        else {
            var d = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd",  item);
            var dt_to = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', d);
            return dt_to;
        }
    }

    function loadPrioritizedList() {
        $("#tasksUL").empty();
    // TDs below have to be 3 more width than the headers 
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",    
            webURL: myURL,
            listName: targetListName,
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Priority_x0020_Number' /><FieldRef Name='Edit_x0020_Link' /><FieldRef Name='Priority' /><FieldRef Name='Top_x0020_Item_x003f_' /><FieldRef Name='Purpose' /><FieldRef Name='Work_x002d_Task_x0020_Order' /><FieldRef Name='Work_x0020_Status' /><FieldRef Name='DueDate' /><FieldRef Name='Task_x0020_Type' /></ViewFields>",
            CAMLQuery: '<Query>' +
            '<OrderBy>' +
            '<FieldRef Name="Priority_x0020_Number" />' +
            '</OrderBy>' +
            '</Query>', 
            CAMLRowLimit: listrowlimit,  
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                    var tdHtml = "<tr class='sortable_row' id=" + $(this).attr("ows_ID") + ">";
                    tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:40px;\">" + PriorityFormat($(this).attr("ows_Priority_x0020_Number"));  + "</td>";
tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:40px;\">" + ($(this).attr("ows_Edit_x0020_Link")).split(", ")[1] + "</td>"; 
 tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:46px;\">" + $(this).attr("ows_Priority") + "</td>";
tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:40px;\">" + TopItem($(this).attr("ows_Top_x0020_Item_x003f_")) + "</td>";
tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:300px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_Purpose")) + "</td>";
 tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:125px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_Work_x002d_Task_x0020_Order")) + "</td>";    
tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:150px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_Work_x0020_Status")) + "</td>";
tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:100px;\">" + FormatDate($(this).attr("ows_DueDate")) + "</td>";
tdHtml = tdHtml + "<td style=\"width:75px;\">" + StringChk($(this).attr("ows_Task_x0020_Type")) + "</td>";
 tdHtml = tdHtml + "</tr>";
                    $("#tasksUL").append(tdHtml);
                });
            }
        });

        $("#tasksUL").sortable({
            containment: "#scroll2",
            helper: fixHelperModified,
            scroll: true,
            axis: "y",
            cursor: "move"
        }).disableSelection();
    }

    //Beginning to save items
    function saveListOrder() {
        $("#Dialog").dialog({ width: 200, height: 100, title: "Saving...", resizable: false, closeOnEscape: false, modal: true });
        alert('Saving new list order.');        
        var total = 0;
        var itemcnt = 0;
        var msgstart = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>";
        var msgend = "</Method>";
        var updatestart = "<Batch OnError='Continue'>";
        var updateend = "</Batch>";
        // process each
        var updatemsg = updatestart;
        $('#tasksUL tr').each(function(index) {
            // here we want to do 'updatecount' at a time to the list
            itemcnt = itemcnt + 1;
            total = total + 1;
            // create the update method for this item
            updatemsg = updatemsg + msgstart;
            updatemsg = updatemsg + "<Field Name='Priority_x0020_Number'>" + total + "</Field>";
            var itemId = $(this).attr("id");
            updatemsg = updatemsg + "<Field Name='ID'>" + itemId + "</Field>";
            updatemsg = updatemsg + msgend;

            // if we hit 100 then save to list and reset counter
            if (itemcnt == 100) {
                itemcnt = 0;
                updatemsg = updatemsg + updateend;
                SaveItem(updatemsg, total);
                updatemsg = updatestart;
            }
        });
        // Now we need to update the last items
        if (itemcnt > 0) {
            updatemsg = updatemsg + updateend;
            SaveItem(updatemsg, total);
        }
        alert('List items saved.  Reloading list.');
        $("#saveid").html("");
        loadPrioritizedList();
        $("#Dialog").dialog('close');
    }

    function SaveItem(updatemsg, total) {
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "UpdateListItems",
            debug:false,
            async: false,
            batchCmd: "Update",
            listName: targetListName,
            updates: updatemsg,
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                $("#saveid").html("Updated " + total + " list items");
            }
        });
    } 


    $(document).ready(function() {
        //alert("jQuery");   
        //alert($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite());
        //$('.listtable').css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $("#Dialog").dialog({ width: 200, height: 100, title: "Loading...", resizable: false, closeOnEscape: false, modal: true });
        $("#msgid").html("Drag list items to save priority.");
        loadPrioritizedList();
        $("#Dialog").dialog('close');
    });
</script>

<div id="msgid">Drag rows to new position to change List Order.</div>
<br/><a id="saveLink" onclick="saveListOrder();" href="#">Save List Order</a> <br/>
<br/>

<!-- Make the widths 3 pixels smaller than the column widths because of styling -->
<div id="scroll2">
<div class="listtable_hdr" width="100%">
<table width="975px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="contents_header" style="width:37px;">List Order</th>
            <th class="contents_header" style="width:42px;">Edit</th>
            <th class="contents_header" style="width:42px;">Priority</th>
            <th class="contents_header" style="width:37px;">Top Item?</th>
            <th class="contents_header" style="width:297px;">Effort/Purpose</th>
            <th class="contents_header" style="width:122px;">Contract-Task Order</th>
            <th class="contents_header" style="width:147px;">Work Status</th>
            <th class="contents_header" style="width:97px;">Action Need Date</th>
            <th class="contents_header" style="width:72px;">Action Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="scrolldiv" class="listtable" style="height:500px;width:995px;">
<table width="975px" >
    <tbody id="tasksUL" >
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div id="savemsg"></div>
<div id="Dialog" title="Loading..." style="display:none;text-align:center;padding-top:20px;"><img src="../SiteAssets//LoadingAnimationBlue.gif" /></div>
```

Thanks again for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure i understand the problem,
but, Did you try this:

```
tdHtml = tdHtml + '<td style=\"width:40px;\"><a href=\"'+($(this).attr("ows_Edit_x0020_Link")).split(", ")[1]+'\">'+ ($(this).attr("ows_Edit_x0020_Link")).split(", ")[1] +'</a></td>';
```

Khalil.

Comment: thanks for the response!  I just tried that but it made the list return no values.

To clarify a bit, basically the problem is that "ows_Edit_x0020_Link" is a SharePoint list item whose values are hyperlinks.  My query is only returning those list values as text, not hyperlinks and I'm trying to fix that.

Comment: Check it now, part of the code disappeared when I post it, I edit it now

Comment: $kdureidy - Thanks for the update - I just tried it, but the list is still not returning any values.

Comment: not sure how did you use my code, where you put it, but i edit it again, replace it with first tdHtml line